# Unzip downloaded file via RestSharp

Tags: c#, api, download, zip, restsharp

I've just downloaded a .zip file with RestSharp and it works great.
Here is my code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://xxx:3080");
        var request = new RestRequest("/xxx/api/download/book/46795403-de-DE", Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer Tokenxxx");
        client.DownloadData(request).SaveAs("C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/myRestSharpResponse.zip");
    }
```

How can i unzip the files automatically now?

Comment: what do you mean by 'automatically'. Do you mean in the code of that program?

Comment: exactly .. there are .html files stored in the zip. My app has to show them in a webview after it downloaded them.

Comment: Once downloaded, you can use ZipFile to extract the zip file https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/hh485723(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Best option would be use a library. I'd suggest you try zipdotnet

Comment: sorry, meant dotnetzip https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/

Answer (score 1):

To unzip your file using [ZipFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
const string zipPath = @"C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/myRestSharpResponse.zip";
const string extractPath = @"C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/ExtractFolder";

client.DownloadData(request).SaveAs(zipPath);

ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
```

Comment: To use "SaveAs" method of "REstSharp" client, please include this namespace : using RestSharp.Extensions;